# how to load a page with GET parameters in grid expander?

Tags: atk4, agiletoolkit

As you know we can load a Page in expander in this way:

```
 $g->addColumn('expander','tickets');
```

But in my situation, the Tickets page have some parameters like this:

```
?page=tickets&tid=1
```

how can I load this page with tid parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make those parameters sticky at the start of your page:

```
$this->api->stickyGET('tid');
```

This parameter will be passed to sub-pages.

See also:

- https://github.com/atk4/docs/blob/master/application/routing/sticky.md

Comment: I didn't understand Romans! I have a grid with expander and each row must open an expander with links like: ?page=tickets&tid=1,?page=tickets&tid=2,?page=tickets&tid=999... how should I tell the expander to send that parameter to the ticket page? Thanks.

Comment: ah, no grid already will pass you parameter which will match the table of your Grid's model. Simply pop var_dump($_GET) to discover.