# Form submission not handled

Tags: atk4

Is there a way to detect why a form is giving the message "Form submission is not handled".

I'm not posting code here, it's a simple form not based on models, but I have made some other forms.

Is there any rule to consider or something that helps me to find out (or debug) why a form is giving a "submission not handled".

Which are the best approaches ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

"Form submission is not handled" appears only in one case - you didn't return javascript action after form check. After checking you need to return some js respond to the browser like this:

```
$form->js()->univ()->alert('Form was submitted')->execute();
```

Don't forget to put ->execute() !!!

Answer (score 0):

Your form is not well submitted. That error appears when the onSubmit function is not called. In this case you will pass the first if from src/lib/Form/Basic.php lateSubmit function:

```
function lateSubmit(){
        if(@$_GET['submit']!=$this->name)return;

        if($this->bail_out===null || $this->isSubmitted()){
            $this->js()->univ()
                ->consoleError('Form '.$this->name.' submission is not handled.'.
                    ' See: http://agiletoolkit.org/doc/form/submit')
                ->execute();
        }
    }
```

To fix this problem, after your form jus add something like:

```
        $this->onSubmit(function($form) use ($bs) {

//            if ($this->isClicked($bs)) {
//                return $this->js()->univ()->redirect($this->app->url());
//            }

//            return $this->js()->univ->redirect($this->app->url('..'));
        });
```

Even if the onSubmit is empty, you will pass the "Form submission is not handled" error.

**Solution #2**

Make those parameters sticky at the start of your page:

```
$this->api->stickyGET('tid');
```

This parameter will be passed to sub-pages.

Source - https://stackoverflow.com/a/18880358/1564840